# Advance - Check material, count them and export to CSV file

Tags: python, materials, scripting, csv

##### Topic starts here, so check it if you need more information about subject:

[How to print material names (two materials) for selected object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248940/how-to-print-material-names-two-materials-for-selected-object-generete-list)

### Main Problem

I need generate list of selected object which will print: name of object, name material 1st index + 2nd index material will be checked on sides (this will be always cube).

### Goal is to try make list like this:

```
#side on 1 dimension is checked with materialside - so max is 2 sides print = 2 (or 1)
#if is none - print = 0
#side on 2 dimension is checked with materialside - so max is 2 sides print = 2 (or 1)
#if is none - print = 0


Model; Material; Edges1Dimension(e.g. width); Edges2Dimesion(e.g. length)
Cube.001; Material 1; 2; 2
Cube.003; Material 2; 2; 0
```

#### Explain:

- Cube.001 - object name
- Material 1 - 1st index material of that selected object
- 2, 2 - numbers of faces which is assigned material with 2nd index of that selected object. (for cube i define as: 2 fronts, and 4 sides [2 for dimiension x axis, and 2 for dimension  y axis] )

Example file:
[image]

Link to file presented up (1 week acces to download from now):
https://we.tl/t-kbbkSjJlpg

Imported part for me is that could be translated into CSV (and open that file by Excel)- i have already list with dimension and  names - now i want to add this next step.

**Thank you for your time - best regards!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again, I shall give you a slight variation on your request, and leave the final adaptation as an exercise.

Here is code that prints the information you want, but not in precisely the format you want.

```py
import bpy

mesh_objs = [ob for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects if ob.type == 'MESH']

def polys(mesh, index):
    n = 0
    for p in mesh.data.polygons:
        if p.material_index == index:
            n += 1
    return n

for mesh in mesh_objs:
    print(mesh.name, end = "; ")
    for index, slot in enumerate(mesh.material_slots):
        print(f"{slot.name}; {polys(mesh, index)}", end = "; ")
    print()
```

and here is a print out from your test file:

```
Cube.001;  Material 1 White; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube.002;  Material 1 White; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube;  Material 1 White; 4; Material Edge; 2; 
Cube 1.001;  Material 1 White; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube 1.002;  Material 3 Red; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube 1;  Material 3 Red; 4; Material Edge; 2; 
Cube 2;  Material 2 Green; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube 2.001;  Material 1 White; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube 2.002;  Material 1 White; 4; Material Edge; 2; 
Cube Rotate;  Material 2 Green; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube Rotate.001;  Material 3 Red; 2; Material Edge; 4; 
Cube Rotate.002;  Material 1 White; 2; Material Edge; 4;
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks like what i needed! I will try use this in my code and I will let you know if this work for me! Thank you!