# How can we render an object including his material name?

Tags: python, rendering, materials, render-layers

I need to render an object in a different material, @FFeller, helped me with the index material geometry node, which allowed me to automate the rendering. But, in the naming the rendered images, didn’t include the material names.
Knowing that I had almost 50 different materials, that I already properly named in a slot material, you can imagine what time-consuming renaming all the images….

And I’m not familiar with python, so is there any help…. Thankx

PS: screenshot to illustrate my question
[image]
[image]

@Marty Fouts,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248940/how-to-print-material-names-two-materials-for-selected-object

Comment: do you want to rename all the render result?

Comment: Yes
Instead of having  the image name : 0001.png,  having the material name : RED_MATERIAL.png
thanks

Comment: thanks , but would you mind show me how I can invoke Python code? please I'm really not familiar with Python in blender. I have some notions but I haven't coded before.

Comment: MATERIAL_NNNN is the material in slot nnnn (- 1?)

Yes in the slot material I named them and identified them by index 

So 0001- is the first material indexed 1 in the -set material index- wish named RED_MATERIAL
And so on….
Hope I’m made it clear 
thanks again @Marty Fouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed material slots on every frame, this code should solve your problem.

EDIT: If you started on frame 1 with the material in slot zero you'll need to change the line that sets `src_string` by changing `index` to `index + 1`.

```py
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

scene = bpy.context.scene
path = Path(scene.render.filepath)
suffix = ".png"

object = bpy.context.active_object
for index in range(len(object.material_slots)):
    src_string = format(index, "04d") + suffix
    src = path / src_string
    dst_string = object.material_slots[index].material.name  + suffix
    dst = path / dst_string
    print(str(src), str(dst))
    src.rename(dst)
```

Paste it into the text editor in the Scripting workspace.  Make sure you've selected the object that has your geometry nodes as the active object.  *After* you've generated the png files, hit the run button.

Comment: I don’t know what I did wrong.  
I select the cube. – I paste the script – I render the animation – and I hit the run – I generate again - ……
Can you tell me? 
@Marty Fouts

Comment: @Kalthoum what do you mean by "I generate again"?  When I said "hit run" I meant the triangle shaped "run" button in the text editor.

Comment: exact I run the scrip with the play_triangle, and generate the rendering. Is that wat I suppose to do?

Comment: First you render, so that all of the files will exist with the 0000.png, 0001.png, etc names.  Then you run the script.  The names _should_ change to match the materials unless I don't understand your description of how you animated.

Comment: I did exactly in that order but I received an error message : "Python script failed, check the message in the system console" and no changes to the names. And you totally get what I need. and thanks again for your time.

Comment: What does it say on the system console?

Comment: I click on -Console- and "copy as Script" : 

here the result:     
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import *
from math import *

#~ PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.9.7 (default, Oct 11 2021, 19:31:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
#~ 
#~ Builtin Modules:       bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
#~ Convenience Imports:   from mathutils import *; from math import *
#~ Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data
#~

Comment: That's the python console.  You need the _system_ console.  If you're on windows, go to the _Window_ menu and hit "Toggle System Console".  Otherwise, you'll have to find out how to do the equivalent yourself.

Comment: multiple addons with the same name:
  'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.0\\3.0\\scripts\\addons\\viewport_vr_preview\\__init__.py'
  'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.0\\3.0\\scripts\\addons\\viewport_vr_preview.py'
multiple addons with the same name:
  'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.0\\3.0\\scripts\\addons\\blenderkit\\__init__.py'
  'C:\\Users\\kalth\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.0\\scripts\\addons\\blenderkit\\__init__.py'

Comment: C:\Users\kalth\Desktop\TEST-MAT\0000.png C:\Users\kalth\Desktop\TEST-MAT\RED_MATERIAL.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1382, in rename
    self._accessor.rename(self, target)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\kalth\\Desktop\\TEST-MAT\\0000.png' -> 'C:\\Users\\kalth\\Desktop\\TEST-MAT\\RED_MATERIAL.png'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: Ignoring the first batch of errors, the last line is telling you that your naming scheme isn't what you think it is.  Open your file browser and go to the TEST-MAT directory.  What are the file names like?

Comment: I've got to run now.  More tomorrow, maybe

Comment: it's probably the suffix.  Check how 'png' is displayed in a list of the files.  Change the suffix line of the script to match.

Comment: It works IT WORKSSSSSSSSSS
The rendering images started by 0001.png
And the script looks for 0000.png
So, I renamed the first render 0000.png. and the magic happened
You don’t know how this is important for me, and how much you helped me
Thanks again for your patience and I learned a lot…
 PS: I add a screenshot of the result

Comment: @Kalthoum Great.  I'm glad you figured it out. Since you're apparently a new user to Blender StackExchange, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps upvote or accept my answer

Comment: Yes, I’m new on the plat form 
May I ask for some modification on the script (I tried by my self but….)
I have a lot of objects that I need to associate to these materials, and I use the output files in the compositor.
The rendered image has the name CUBE_ONE_0000.PNG
SO, please, what did I need to change in the script?
PS: add image to illustrate
Thanks again

Comment: This probably qualifies as a new question, by stack exchange standards.  Please write a new question -- it's ok to use the URL of this one as a reference so you don't have to duplicate details and ask how to extend the script so that it handles multiple objects.